# Amazon ses giving email address unverified. when it is already verified

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

I am getting following errors while sending email from nirajp123@gmail.com. I have already verified this email. While same code and access keys I am able to send email from other emails to same to emails. I am not getting any clue as what might be happening.

I can also send email through the ses console from nirajp123@gmail.com

```
[org.apache.http.wire] >> "Action=SendEmail&Version=2010-12-01&Source=nirajp123%40gmail.com&Destination.ToAddresses.member.1=waraichseerat%40gmail.com&Message.Subject.Data=asdasas&Message.Body.Html.Data=%3Cp%3EYour+content+here.dfsfdsf%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cimg+src%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flogo%3Faddressid%3D154%26emailid%3D14252%27%2F%3E"
[org.apache.http.wire] >> "POST / HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[org.apache.http.wire] >> "Host: email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com[\r][\n]"
[org.apache.http.wire] >> "X-Amz-Date: Thu, 08 Jan 2015 15:34:40 GMT[\r][\n]"
[org.apache.http.wire] >> "X-Amzn-Authorization: AWS3 AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJN7R2R3U7RUUVPPA,Algorithm=HmacSHA256,SignedHeaders=Host;X-Amz-Date,Signature=ujSfOjFvwgC/tRu6A16PrhtXSzfH/oS7aztaV+9p5jw=[\r][\n]"
[org.apache.http.wire] >> "User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/1.7.13 Linux/3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.5-b02/1.8.0_05[\r][\n]"
[org.apache.http.wire] >> "Date: Thu, 08 Jan 2015 15:34:40 GMT[\r][\n]"
[org.apache.http.wire] >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
[org.apache.http.wire] >> "Content-Length: 311[\r][\n]"
[org.apache.http.wire] >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[org.apache.http.wire] >> "[\r][\n]"
[org.apache.http.headers] >> POST / HTTP/1.1
[org.apache.http.headers] >> Host: email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
[org.apache.http.headers] >> X-Amz-Date: Thu, 08 Jan 2015 15:34:40 GMT
[org.apache.http.headers] >> X-Amzn-Authorization: AWS3 AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJN7R2R3U7RUUVPPA,Algorithm=HmacSHA256,SignedHeaders=Host;X-Amz-Date,Signature=ujSfOjFvwgC/tRu6A16PrhtXSzfH/oS7aztaV+9p5jw=
[org.apache.http.headers] >> User-Agent: aws-sdk-java/1.7.13 Linux/3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 Java_HotSpot(TM)_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.5-b02/1.8.0_05
[org.apache.http.headers] >> Date: Thu, 08 Jan 2015 15:34:40 GMT
[org.apache.http.headers] >> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
[org.apache.http.headers] >> Content-Length: 311
[org.apache.http.headers] >> Connection: Keep-Alive
[org.apache.http.wire] >> "Action=SendEmail&Version=2010-12-01&Source=nirajp123%40gmail.com&Destination.ToAddresses.member.1=nirajp123%40gmail.com&Message.Subject.Data=asdasas&Message.Body.Html.Data=%3Cp%3EYour+content+here.dfsfdsf%3C%2Fp%3E%3Cimg+src%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flogo%3Faddressid%3D153%26emailid%3D14251%27%2F%3E"
[org.apache.http.wire] << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request[\r][\n]"
[org.apache.http.wire] << "x-amzn-RequestId: dc6deb22-974b-11e4-b425-2f4b2ec87708[\r][\n]"
[org.apache.http.wire] << "Content-Type: text/xml[\r][\n]"
[org.apache.http.wire] << "Content-Length: 276[\r][\n]"
[org.apache.http.wire] << "Date: Thu, 08 Jan 2015 15:34:40 GMT[\r][\n]"
[org.apache.http.wire] << "[\r][\n]"
[org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
[org.apache.http.headers] << HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
[org.apache.http.headers] << x-amzn-RequestId: dc6deb22-974b-11e4-b425-2f4b2ec87708
[org.apache.http.headers] << Content-Type: text/xml
[org.apache.http.headers] << Content-Length: 276
[org.apache.http.headers] << Date: Thu, 08 Jan 2015 15:34:40 GMT
[com.amazonaws.http.impl.client.SdkHttpClient] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
[org.apache.http.wire] << "<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">[\n]"
[org.apache.http.wire] << "  <Error>[\n]"
[org.apache.http.wire] << "    <Type>Sender</Type>[\n]"
[org.apache.http.wire] << "    <Code>MessageRejected</Code>[\n]"
[org.apache.http.wire] << "    <Message>Email address is not verified.</Message>[\n]"
[org.apache.http.wire] << "  </Error>[\n]"
[org.apache.http.wire] << "  <RequestId>dc6deb22-974b-11e4-b425-2f4b2ec87708</RequestId>[\n]"
[org.apache.http.wire] << "</ErrorResponse>[\n]"
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by creating a new user and assigning it the SES access. When I use the credentials of the new user, I am able to send emails using Amazon api.